# Wrong Pageable data displayed in my browser

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to display data from MySQL database using spring data with Pageable class.

I am new in Spring Data and unfortunately I get all rows shown in my browser, instead of some.

Find below my code

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**ProductDaoImpl**

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.model.Product;

@Repository
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Page<Product> getPageProduct(@Param("libelleProduct")String libelleProduct, Pageable pageable) {     
        List<Product> listProduct = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("From Product p where p.libelleProduct like :libelleProduct").setParameter("libelleProduct", libelleProduct).list();
        Page<Product> pageProduct =  new PageImpl<Product>(listProduct, pageable, listProduct.size());
        return pageProduct;
    }

}
```

**ProductService**

```
package com.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.dao.ProductDao;
import com.model.Product;

@Service
@Transactional
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;

    public ProductDao getProductDao() {
        return productDao;
    }

    public Page<Product> getPageProduct(String libelleProduct, int page, int size) {
        return productDao.getPageProduct(libelleProduct, new PageRequest(page, size));
    }

}
```

**ProductController**

```
package com.controller;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.model.Product;
import com.service.ProductService;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    public Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProductController.class);

    public ProductController(){
        System.out.println("ProductController()");
    }

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="/listedesproduit", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Page<Product> getPageProduct(){
        Page<Product> pageProduct = service.getPageProduct("%e%",0, 1);
        pageProduct.forEach(p->System.out.println(p.getLibelleProduct()));
        return pageProduct;
    }

}
```

Find below the result I get in my browser, I get four rows shown instead of one on each page.

```
{"content":[{"idProduct":2,"libelleProduct":"sprite","qteProduct":5},{"idProduct":3,"libelleProduct":"eku","qteProduct":5},{"idProduct":4,"libelleProduct":"33 export","qteProduct":5},{"idProduct":6,"libelleProduct":"guiness","qteProduct":5}],"size":1,"number":0,"numberOfElements":4,"sort":null,"totalPages":4,"totalElements":4,"firstPage":true,"lastPage":false}
```

Can you please help me to find what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong here:

```
List<Product> listProduct = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("From Product p where p.libelleProduct like :libelleProduct")
    .setParameter("libelleProduct", libelleProduct).list();
Page<Product> pageProduct = new PageImpl<Product>(listProduct, pageable, listProduct.size());
```

You are basically loading all the query results and then returning it in a `PageImpl`, which is just a wrapper of the data.

You should create a `PagingAndSortingRepository` and call query methods passing the `Pageable`, which is the page request to be executed by the repository.

If this doesn't make sense to you, look for tutorials about "spring data paging" like [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-part-5-paging-and-sorting) and take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html).